# WCF Basics with a Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am looking into WCF specifically in relation to Silverlight.

Can someone tell me if I am correct in thinking that I can create a WCF Service, and expose a TCP endpoint using a Windows Service that my Silverlight app can use?

I have managed to expose this using IIS but it would be good if we could bypass using IIS as some of our customers don't like it.

UPDATE...

OK I have created a WCF Service Library (RemoteClientLib with IRemoteClients defining my service contracts and RemoteClients Implementing this Interface) and a Windows Service to host it. I have added an App.config to both projects that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RemoteClientLib.RemoteClients" behaviorConfiguration="remoteBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="RemoteClientLib.IRemoteClients" bindingConfiguration="remoteBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:4520/RemoteClients"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="remoteBinding"></binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="remoteBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I created a project installer to install the service and started it up but when I try and add a service reference in my silverlight project I get 
'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: TCP endpoint is incompatible with iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx) on codeproject.com I've used for self-hosting WCF services. It would be pretty straight forward to build it into a Windows service. Consider [Topshelf](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/) as a Windows service framework too.

Comment: How do I specify which/what port the Service will be using in order to connect to it with my client. Using IIS hosting the port is specified in the site bindings and is not done anywhere in the code.

Comment: The port is expressed in your WCF Service Library's .Config

Comment: OK I have created a WCF Service Library and a Windows Service to host it. I have added an App.config to both projects that looks like this:

Answer (score 1):

You can create a windows service that acts as your own host.  Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) to the various methods available to hosting a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so. Any of the bindings you can use while in IIS, you should be able to use with self-hosting.